# Can I have a "Wrapping reference" in PHP?

Tags: php

Can I have a function that returns a reference to something wrapping it's input?

```
<?php
function &wrap(&$data){
    return ['hee' => [$data]];
}

$data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$outside = &wrap($data);

$data[] = 'd';
// I want the contents of $outside to have changed here
```

I can do it the other way round by writing an "Unwrap" function that returns a reference to something inside `$outside` and then I can change that reference, but this way it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
function &wrap(&$data){
    return ['hee' => [$data]];
}
```

To:

```
function wrap(&$data){
    return ['hee' => [&$data]];
}
```

And then `$outside = &wrap($data);` to `$outside = wrap($data);`

Full example:

```
<?php

function wrap(&$data){
    return ['hee' => [&$data]];
}

$data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$outside = wrap($data);

$data[] = 'd';

print_r($outside);
```

Results:

```
andy-mbp:test centerorbit$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [hee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                    [3] => d
                )

        )

)
```